# After converting xml to json unable to access the data

Tags: c#, xml, json, angularjs

I am learning angularjs.

When i want to access xml file,i am unable to do it i used xml_strjson
 this method is converting the data xml to json but unable to access in html file
here is my code:

```
enter code here<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="">
<head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.26/angular.min.js">   </script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://demos.amitavroy.com/learningci/assets   /js/xml2json.js" charset="UTF-8"></script>
  <script>
        function customersController($scope, $http) {
        $http.get("http://localhost:13087/Data.xml")
        .success(function (response) {
            $scope.lstComapanies = x2js.xml_str2json(response);
            console.log($scope.lstComapanies);

            alert(response);
        });
    }

</script>
     <title></title>
      </head>
   <body ng-controller="customersController">
     <table>
        <tbody>
               <tr ng-repeat="CompanyModel in lstComapanies">
                <!-- $index for duplicate values -->
                  <td class="border">
                      <label>{{ CompanyModel }}</label>
                </td>

            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

my json data

```
{
    "__cnt": 8,
    "CompanyModel": [
        {
            "__cnt": 7,
            "BacklogSum": "646",
            "BacklogSum_asArray": [
                "646"
            ],
            "BillingSum": "607",
            "BillingSum_asArray": [
                "607"
            ],
            "BookingSum": "646",
            "BookingSum_asArray": [
                "646"
            ],
            "CashflowSum": "$-4809038.45",
            "CashflowSum_asArray": [
                "$-4809038.45"
            ],
            "LstCompanies": {
                "__cnt": 1,
                "_i:nil": "true"
            },
            "LstCompanies_asArray": [
                {
                    "__cnt": 1,
                    "_i:nil": "true"
                }
            ],
            "Name": "OPTERNA AM, INC. ",
            "Name_asArray": [
                "OPTERNA AM, INC. "
            ],
            "Number": "2000",
            "Number_asArray": [
                "2000"
            ]
        }
    ],
    "_xmlns:i": "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance",

}
```

Comment: try parsing JSON.parse(your_converted_data) .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create a main module for your app, and then add the controller to it.

First, change your script to this:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('customersController', ['$scope', '$http',
 function($scope, $http){
    $http.get("http://localhost:13087/Data.xml")
        .success(function (response) {
            $scope.lstComapanies = x2js.xml_str2json(response);
            console.log($scope.lstComapanies);

            alert(response);
    })
}]);
```

then set up your app and controller correctly

```
<body ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="customersController">
        <table>
            .... etc
```

also, as pointed out above you will need to change your ng-repeat.

```
<tr ng-repeat="objects in lstComapanies.CompanyModel">
```

Comment: hi sorry above one showing blank page i modifed the script as u given but no change in result but when i check with alert i can see the data

Comment: @user1983379 since you changed the name of ng-repeat to objects did you change the binding to {{objects}}

Comment: hi Alex Scott my issue was sloved by changin this code   $scope.lstComapanies = obj.ArrayOfCompanyModel.CompanyModel;

Answer (score 0):

It's simple:

```
<tr ng-repeat="CompanyModel in lstComapanies.CompanyModel">
```

See your JSON. It starts with an object with two attributes:
1. ____cnt = 8 (sounds like count)
2. CompanyModel = Array of objects

So the repeater expects an array and you gave him an object. But this object includes your array.

JSON means Java Script Obect Notation and when you have JSON parsed in JavaScript it ends up in an object or array. So you can directly acces everythin in your lstComapanies (should be lstCampanies?).

If not working do the hole thing:

1. Module
2. Controller to define scope
3. use controller and iterate over data

   > ```
   > angular.module('myApp', [])
   >  .controller('customersController', ['$scope', '$http',
   >   $scope.lstComapanies = {};
   >   function($scope, $http){
   >     $http.get("http://localhost:13087/Data.xml")
   >       .success(function (response) {
   >         $scope.lstComapanies = JSON.parse(x2js.xml_str2json(response));
   >         console.log($scope.lstComapanies);
   >
   >         alert(response);
   >     })
   > }]);
   >
   > <body ng-app="myApp">
   >   <div ng-controller="customersController">
   >   ...
   >     <tr ng-repeat="CompanyModel in lstComapanies.CompanyModel">
   >       <td>{{ CompanyModel.__cnt }}</td>
   >       <td>{{ CompanyModel.BacklogSum }}</td>
   >       <td>
   >         <span ng-repeat="sum in CompanyModel.BacklogSum_asArray">{{ sum }}</span>
   >       </td>
   >   </tr>
   >   ...
   >   </div>
   > ```
   >
   > NOTE: JSON.parse() doesn't exist in all browser, see here: [Safely turning a JSON string into an object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45015/safely-turning-a-json-string-into-an-object)

But normaly I would place the http get stuff in a factory or service class which can be injected in to any controller that needs access to the data. Then next I would you promises which when succeed return desired data over specific API functions like getCompanies()

Comment: Then you have to add an angular module as described by @Alex Scott, too.